# Production Test Execution "Could not run tests on class ..."

Tags: unit-test

While running my test cases within my prod environment, I noticed quite a few messages as the title describes, and I don't understand why. Do you have any insight on why this is happening? It seems to be dropping my code coverage below what I have in my sandboxes as well. Even when I code my test cases with *SeeAllData=false*

Test Class:
[image: Test Class]

Test Results of Class:
[image: TestResults]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is actually a bug in salesforce. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0FeAAK

Since the tests are all passing, you'll still be able to deploy to production, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I still have the issue atm even after trying those "workarounds". Any ideas ?

Comment: This occasionally still happens in my org and I just have to run the tests again. Is this blocking you from deploying to production?